# How this code Compile and Run?

Tags: java, object, constructor

```
class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        new Animal();
    }
}

class Animal {

    Animal() {
        System.out.println("sound! sound!");
    }
}
```

How this code compiles fine as we know that without using reference variable to a class we cannot use new operator alone and here I am just mentioning "new Animal();"and the constructor is getting executed without any error, How??

Comment: "we know that without using reference variable to a class we cannot use new operator alone" -- maybe we _don't_ know that

Comment: It's not required to store the object that `new` returns in a variable.

Comment: Please let us know what dumb website said that you cannot use `new` operator alone, so we can all shame it out of existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous object.  After the execution of constructor; the GC will clean up this object.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-anonymous-object-instantiation

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> we know that without using reference variable to a class we cannot use
>   new operator alone

You can. The resultant object reference simply isn't assigned to anything, and the allocated/instantiated object can't be accessed further. Note that without a holding reference your instantiated Animal object will be a candidate for immediate garbage collection (notwithstanding the fact that `main()` will exit immediately in your example)

Answer (score 1):

you can do `new Animal();` as much as you want, the only thing is you create the object but has no reference that you can use later to work with the object...

so this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    new Animal();
}
```

is fine, it compiles and runs without a problem

---

here is just an example taken from the JDK :

from the `DateFormat` class

```
public final String format(Date date)
{
    return format(date, new StringBuffer(),
                  DontCareFieldPosition.INSTANCE).toString();
}
```

a `StringBuffer` object is created anonymously and passed to the format method...

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are not assigning your `new Animal()` to a variable, it doesn't mean it won't be initialised.

You just can't use it or refer to it again.

Comment: Unless it stores a reference to itself in global memory (bad idea, but someone likely did at some point).